# WPF - Simulate Mouse Move without moving the Mouse

Tags: wpf, mousemove, sendmessage

I've a WPF window, which I transfer over websockets via https://wow.codeplex.com/ !
The problem now is, I need to simulate Mouse Events on that window. Clicks already work directly in WPF, but MouseMove does not. So I tried to use SendMessage API, but this does not work!

The problem is, I can not use APIs which really move the cursor, because multiple Clients could be connected!

Comment: *Clicks already work directly in WPF, but MouseMove does not*... this makes no sense. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It makes sense. Look at: https://wow.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WpfServer/WpfServer/StreamableWindow.cs 
There you see how Clicks are simulated, but you cant use the same way for MouseMove, it will not work!

Comment: I didn't say that simulating clicks makes no sense... I clearly highlighted the text that makes no sense in my comment. I also asked *What are you actually trying to achieve?* but as you chose to ignore that too, good luck with finding your own solution.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question. As I said, I try to send a WPF Window via Websockets to a Browser (as you see on the Codeplex Project). To control the app, I need to simulate Mouse Events on the App! This simulation works for MouseClicks, but not for MouseMove.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect some thing is overloading the mouse move events in the codeplex custom window and returning an unhandled exception. Put a debug pointer in the custom window mouse move and watch. You will get it resolved.

Comment: What do you mean? How should overwriting MouseMove events help me to simulate them? They are raised when the mouse is moved, and that is what I try to simulate!